# content for android:empty isn't shown in listview in tab layout

Tags: android

I have a tab layout with 3 tab contents, in the first tab content I use the following listview to display:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView  android:id="@+id/listView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#009ACD"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dip"

               android:maxWidth="200dip"
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="*You haven't written any   notes yet*" />
```

so when my first tab content is empty, it should display that text in textview, but mine doesn't display, please help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '+' before the id in

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
```

Comment: Cool User7s.... Just adding the link to listview for easier access: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html